# replace double quotes within double quoted strings

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

We have some GUI issues that converted all our xml entities to their character format and stored in our Oracle DB.
The biggest problem is with `&quot;` being converted to " within quoted xml attribute values.

```
<?xml version=...>
<Fetch searchstr=""brown fox" child* !"big planes"" begin="yesterday" ...>   
    <otherele>...</otherele>
    <some>...</some>
</Fetch>
```

I need to fix it by converting it to:

```
<?xml version=...>
<Fetch searchstr="&quot;brown fox&quot; child* !&quot;big planes&quot;" begin="yesterday" ...>
    <otherele>...</otherele>
    <some>...</some>
</Fetch>
```

I wrote this to fix the issue and it works fine.

```
set content = replace (content, 
                       regexp_substr(content, '<Fetch searchstr=".+" begin='),
                       '<Fetch searchstr="' || 
                       replace(regexp_replace(content, 
                                              '<Fetch searchstr="(.+)" begin=|.',
                                              '\1'), 
                               '"', '&quot;') 
                       || '"  begin=')
```

How can I make this simpler and more efficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get the following substring:

> "brown fox" child* !"big planes"

.. and replace quotation marks with: *&quot*;

```
SET DECLARE OFF;

SELECT  SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str, '""', 1, 1))
||      REPLACE(SUBSTR(str, INSTR(str, '""', 1, 1) + 1, INSTR(str, '""', -1, 1) - INSTR(str, '""', 1, 1)), '"', '&quot;')
||      SUBSTR(str, INSTR(str, '""', -1, 1) + 1)
AS col
FROM
(
SELECT '<?xml version=...><Fetch searchstr=""brown fox" child* !"big planes"" begin="yesterday" ...><otherele>...</otherele><some>...</some></Fetch>' AS str
FROM DUAL
);
```

The result:

```
<?xml version=...><Fetch searchstr="&quot;brown fox&quot; child* !&quot;big planes&quot;" begin="yesterday" ...><otherele>...</otherele><some>...</some></Fetch>
```